# Chess FEN winner

Tags: online-chess, fen, winning

I'm new to Chess FEN notation and I'm making an online chess game, but I have one problem, I need to check after every new move if there is a winner and which one is a winner.

Can I extract that information from FEN notation ?

Answer (score 3):

FEN ([Forsyth-Edwards Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)) is a way of recording the current position on the chess board - piece positions, active colour, castling possibilities, en passant target, half move clock, full move number. The result of the game is not included.